# Chinese filename as an attachment in email

Tags: vb.net, email-attachments

Following is simple code to send the mail with an attachment:
/**************************************************/

```
        Dim msgMail As New System.Web.Mail.MailMessage
        Dim rcpName As String

        Dim client As New SmtpClient

        Dim i As Integer
        Dim recips_addr() As String = Split(to_address, ";")
        Dim recips_name() As String = Split(to_name, ";")

        For i = 0 To recips_addr.Length - 1
            rcpName = """" & recips_name(i) & """"
            msgMail.To = rcpName & recips_addr(i) & ";"
        Next

        msgMail.From = from_address
        msgMail.Subject = subject
        msgMail.BodyFormat = System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Html
        msgMail.Body = message
        msgMail.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8


        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(attachment_path) Then attachment_path = "NONE"
        If (attachment_path <> "NONE") Then
            Dim att As New System.Web.Mail.MailAttachment(attachment_path)
            msgMail.Attachments.Add(att)

        End If

        If send_to_sender Then
            msgMail.Bcc = from_address
        End If



        msgMail.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = My.Settings.smtp_Server
        msgMail.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
        msgMail.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
        msgMail.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        msgMail.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        msgMail.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = My.Settings.emailUsername
        msgMail.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = My.Settings.emailPassword


        System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(msgMail)
```

/**************************************************/

Now, the query is when i send a pdf file as an attachment using above code and file name is 'Report_出生地_出生地_出生地_6023.pdf'.
when i get the mail in my inbox the name of the file becomes 'Report____6023.pdf'.
I don't know why attachment filenames are changing.
Please help !!!!

Comment: Anybody ......... please help :(

Comment: who are you using to send the mail from?

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, but with no luck. I created a pdf with that file name on my dev machine and send it to my Gmail account from my work email just fine, it didn't change anything. Makes me wonder if it's the mail client your sending this from or opening it from.

Comment: Well, I am using the gmail server.

Comment: Can you copy n paste your code snippet which is working.....

Comment: Any body have any idea ?

Comment: How do i do subject encoding ????

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'subject encoding'? It seem's to be an issue with your client your sending it from OR receiving it from that would be doing this.